# Detect when global variables are used (Linter notification or other static analysis tools)

Tags: python, static-analysis

In a rush, I often forget the `self.` before properties:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
class Game:
  agent_speed = 1

@dataclass
class Agent:
  x: int
  def move(self):
    # Here, I forgot self.
    x += Game.agent_speed

a = Agent(1)
a.move()
print(a.x)
```

More generally, I would love being warned that the method `move()` is accessing two global variables: `Game` and `x` to detect such mistakes.
I tried pylint, but it doesn't care about such things, and flake8 probably also does the same.
Is there any way I can get this piece of information about my code?

EDIT:

I'm only interested in forgotten `self.` statement parts, but I know that it can't be done in python, which is why I am instead asking this question about global variables usage.
As @Codist said, using global variables is perfectly legal so I should not call what I want linter warnings (I renamed the question to linter notifications).
Yes, I'd like not all global variable usages to be listed, but only ones which are inside class methods. If it's not possible, then I expect myself to be able to filter out the results to be able to keep only the ones which are relevant to methods.
Finally, if an IDE provides this piece of information (the missing `self.`, it's also good enough for me.

Comment: `dataclass`, `Agent` and `a` are also "global" in this context. This would generate way too many false positives (just these 11 lines of code would generate 3 false positives).

Comment: Why would that constitute a warning? It's perfectly legal

Comment: Thank you for the question. I'm talking about the context of class methods, so the move() function in this case. Everything outside of the class methods I won't care about. And even if there are false positives, I can filter them out, which is why I am talking about getting all uses of global variables (and yes, you're right in the sense that I should not call it a warning) to be able to then make educated guesses on which ones are normal and which ones are not